# repository cloned using SmartGit but shows <missing> in Directory panel

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys, smartgit

I have a repository on Github and want to clone it to my laptop. I'm able to clone it with SmartGit but can't see anything on the directory panel. It shows "missing" besides the name of the cloned repository.

Is there anything wrong with the keys I have? I didn't generate the keys because I took them from another account that I have at school.
I've stored both keys (private and public) in my laptop in:
C:\users\owner.ssh\id_rsa folder.

The Authentication SmartGit I selected is "use SmartGit as SSH client".

"Known Credentials" I have are the following:
Repository
Git:ssh://git@github.com
Details
Private key: C:\Users\owner.ssh\rd_rsa

I'm new to Git and I can't figure it out what is wrong...I'd appreciate any help, suggestion!.Thanks

Comment: Is .git/ directory present? What does "git status" display when invoked in the repository root?

Answer (score 1):

The problem I had was that I should've stored the ssh folder (where the private and public keys are) in the wamp/www folder not in the users folder.

I then updated the credentials in SmartGit (first I removed the known credentials and then I cloned the repo from github. SmartGit asked the new credentials. Here I wrote the path to the private key (now in the wamp/www folder) and finally I entered the password.

The repo was then cloned in the same wamp/www folder. And voila! Everything is fine now.